# Which IE add-on is crashing my application

Tags: c#, federated-identity

Case: I have a a websites which authenticates to a second SSO website using federated authentication.

1. Go to the main website
2. Redirect to the SSO authentication site -> and you fill in the correct credentials
3. go back to main with authentication cookies -> crash

Extra info from the error logs:

- It's always in an IE browser (FF and Chrome work perfectly)
- I can't reproduce the problem myself: tested on every operating system and browser version with [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) nor can my colluegues.
- When contacting end-users who have the problem. They consistently have it in IE. When asked to use another browser it works.

My current guess is that it's due to some IE-add-on. But I do not know which one and this is a bit of a guess. The fact that it happens on end-users computers means I have no control over those computers and I'm unable to go look on their screen and check out which plug-ins they have.

Are their ways to check this? and find out which add-on's are installed on an end-users pc?

The error is this one:

> The token '>' was expected but found 't'. Line 1, position 1572.

Stacktrace:

> at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) at
>   System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowTokenExpected(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, String expected, Char found) at
>   System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadStartElement() at
>   System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read() at
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteNode(XmlDictionaryReader reader,
>   Boolean defattr) at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader
>   reader, Boolean defattr) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.ReadInnerXml(XmlReader
>   reader, Boolean onStartElement) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.ReadRSTRXml(XmlReader
>   reader, RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr, WSTrustSerializationContext
>   context, WSTrustConstantsAdapter trustConstants) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.ReadXmlElement(XmlReader
>   reader, RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr, WSTrustSerializationContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.CreateResponse(XmlReader
>   reader, WSTrustSerializationContext context, WSTrustResponseSerializer
>   responseSerializer, WSTrustConstantsAdapter trustConstants) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.ReadXml(XmlReader
>   reader, WSTrustSerializationContext context) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationSerializer.CreateResponse(WSFederationMessage
>   message, WSTrustSerializationContext context) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage
>   message, WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage
>   message) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage
>   message, WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityToken(SignInResponseMessage
>   message) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityToken(HttpRequest
>   request) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest
>   request) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: You can ask your users to either run [IE with addons disabled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmar/archive/2010/09/15/running-internet-explorer-9-beta-problems-without-addons-use-iexplore-exe-extoff.aspx) or ask them to open up DevTools and send you a capture of the network traffic.

Comment: We've tried that a couple of times, but we haven't get the end users to press the right buttons yet. (They aren't that computer savy)

Comment: And a remote assistance or skype so they can share their screen?